# Angular ReferenceError in service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, reference

I have following service in Ionic/Cordova application. 
I would like to use loading message using $ionicLoading, but I always got error:

```
ReferenceError: $ionicLoading is not defined
```

How can i pass $ionicLoading into service?

Thanks for any help.

```
/**
 * Service for making calls
 */
.factory('DialService', function() {
    return {
        makeCall: function(number) {
            $ionicLoading.show({
                template: 'TEST',
                duration: 1000
            });

            window.cordova.plugins.DirectCallPlugin.call(number, callSuccessCallback, callFailCallback);
        }
    };

    var callSuccessCallback = function() {
        console.log("Success call");
    };

    var callFailCallback = function() {
        console.log("Fail calll");
        $ionicLoading.show({
            template: 'Error during call dial',
            duration: 1000
        });
    };

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transform this :

```
.factory('DialService', function() {
```

into this :

```
.factory('DialService', function($ionicLoading) {
```

And make sure that :

- the script is loaded in your `index.html`
- `ionic` is declared as a dependency of your angular module